# React server-side rendering cannot call web api correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs

**I know. bad title**
I'm using [Asp.Net ReactServices](http://[1][https://github.com/aspnet/NodeServices]) for `React` server-side rendering.

I have this part of code in one of my react component `componentWillMount`:

```
fetch( 'http://localhost:5000/api/Index/GetData',
{
    method: 'get'
} )
.then( (res) => {
    console.log(res.status); // 200
    console.log('first then');
    return res.json();
} )
.then( (res) => {
    console.log( 'second then' );
    return res;
} )
.catch( err => {
    console.log( err )
} );
```

In browser I get `first then` and `second then` message.
but in server-side I only get `first then` wihout an error.
Did I misuse fetch?
Forget `Promise`?
Or calling Web API is not correct?

Comment: Your code doesn't handle error responses, add additional callback into then function to see error response, then(successFn, errorFn)

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly sorry. forgot paste that part

Comment: Visual studio has the greatest feature - break points! Check out is your second promise even hitting server endpoint

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly. I check that too. and yes. if its not hitting server never get inside first promise. I even get status 200 in first promise

Comment: Are you sure you need 2 identical promise resolvers? As I recall, first _then_ passes value to second _then_, maybe in server rendering you don't have access to res.json() method? Log everything to be sure

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly. No I'm not sure. that's why I post this question :). let me more try and update it

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly. its look like you were right. `res` have `body` prop. but I cant get data from it now but working on it. and I have new problem can I change clientside `fetch` to one promise? and check if its server or client for using `json` or `body`?

Comment: I would suggest to check it inside single resolve function, just check _if(res.json) { return res.json() } else return res.body_